# XSync - what does the discard parameter mean?

Tags: x11

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xsync), calling `XSync(dpy, 1)` discards the events in the queue, but what does this really mean? If they are not discarded, are they sent twice (once by the `XSync()` call and a second time when the queue is emptied normally)? Or is it just like a garbage collector (the events get discarded anyway just a later time)?

Answer (score 1):

[`XSync`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSync.html) waits until the request output buffer is emptied (sent to the server). If the `discard` parameter is `True`, this function will throw away all queued events. These events are received from the X server.

Consider the following protocol exchange:

```
C -> S  QueryKeymap request
                                C <- S ConfigureNotify event
                                C <- S QueryKeymap reply
```

You called `XQueryKeymap` in your client application which sents a `QueryKeymap` protocol message to the server. While doing so, you resized the window, hence the `ConfigureNotify` event.

If you run `XSync(display, False)` after your `XQueryKeymap`, then the client will wait until the reply is received. A next `XPending(display)` call will return the number of queued events which is `1` for the `ConfigureNotify` event above.

When `XSync(display, True)` was used instead, then `XPending(display)` returns `0` for the above case.

If your code is to be used by others, please save their time by **not** using `True`. For an example of what can go wrong when using `True`, see http://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1859.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you misconcept two things: X requests with X events, it's not the same. In short:

X requets:

> ... A client application sends requests to the X server over this connection. These requests are made by the Xlib functions that are called in the client application. ...

X events:

> ... Many Xlib functions cause the X server to generate events, and the user's typing or moving the pointer can generate events asynchronously. The X server returns events to the client ...

For more info check [this](http://www.tronche.com/gui/x/) - it's very helpful.

XSync called that way: `XSync(dpy, False)` does two things (according to manul that you pointed):

> The XSync function flushes the output buffer and then waits until all requests have been received and processed by the X server.

XSync called that way: `XSync(dpy, True)` does those two things above plus additional one: discards (processes) all events in the queue.

> If you passed True, XSync() discards all events in the queue, including those events that were on the queue before XSync() was called.

For example (pseudocode):

```
sendEvent2Xserver() //for example by pressing the key
endEvent2Xserver() //for example by mouse button press
XSendEvent() //sending chosen event to X server
XSync(dpy, True) // after this call, it's guaranteed that all the previous events were processed by the server
```

Comment: What is exactly meant by "discards"? I read it as "throws away". For example, the X server sends a ButtonRelease event but if the client does a <code>XSync(dpy, True)</code> before processing the complete queue the event is lost? OTOH, you wrote it processes the events, so perhaps it means that it handles all the replies from the X server (like BadWindow errors and such) before returning?

Comment: nothing is lost, as I wrote events are processed by the server. XSync(dpy, 1) synchronizes execution between X client and X server. After XSync(dpy, 1) call is made you're guaranteed that all previous requests & events are processed (it's like glFinish() from OpenGL) by the X server.